# Formatting answer boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I am still very new to `LaTeX` and was drawn to its chemistry packages.  Since this is my first semester using `LaTeX` for reports, however this class requires *pre-lab* reports to be submitted as well.  Anyway, long story short this lab will require a **LOT** of data and would like to organise it better in my copy of the pre-lab report.  Rather than keeping it in my notebook hastily written.  But, it is very messy and have no idea how to format it.  I can I think `\hrule` it to various measurements but there must be an easier way to pad everything right to the furthest question preceding the colon so everything is aligned properly.

Maybe there is a nicer way of doing the boxes as well as I am eager to learn this much as I can for my future scientific career.

Below is the area in question:

```
\section*{Data}
Boiling point at first drop: \answerbox \\
Boiling point at last drop: \answerbox \\
Tared flask weight with decanted solution (1.0 mg): \answerbox \\
Mass of essential oil after evaporation: \answerbox \\
Percent of essential oil based on mass of caraway oil: \answerbox \\
Mass of 2,4-DNP (\ce{C16H18O4N4}): \answerbox \\
Melting point of 2,4-DNP: \answerbox \\
Amount of carvone originally extracted: \answerbox \\
Amount of limonene in the oil: \answerbox \\
Percent of limonene: \answerbox \\
Percent of carvone: \answerbox \\
\tikz \draw[fill=yellow!3] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, -2in) node[pos=.14]   {Notes (Calculations/Odours):};
```

My preamble is here:

```
% Preamble
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Definitions (do not change this)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule

\makeatletter                           % Title
\def\printtitle{%                       
    {\centering \@title\par}}
\makeatother                                    

\makeatletter                           % Author
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\centering \large \@author}}               
\makeatother                            

\newcommand\answerbox{%%
         \fbox{\rule{2.5cm}{0pt}\rule[-0.2ex]{0pt}{2ex}}}
```

[image: This is what I have now/like to do]

Comment: Please have a look on the `exam` class -- it has support for such `answerboxes` (however, they are named differently)

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ll}Stuff on left & Answer on right\\Next left & Next right\\...\end{tabular}` ??

Comment: I was considering using a table as it should line up easier but felt there had to be a good class, exam seems promising though too.

Comment: I wouldn't use `exam` for this. Not just to draw some boxes. If you were teaching the class, sure, it might be useful. But for preparing your pre lab report? It will just complicate things. At least, that's what I'd think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pretty 'hack' ;-)

I put the descriptions into a `comma separated list` which is displayed by `\MakeTable[options for answerbox]{width of description column}{width of answerbox}[Heading of notes box]<height of notes box>`

More features could be added, but require time ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Definitions (do not change this)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule

\makeatletter                           % Title
\def\printtitle{%                       
    {\centering \@title\par}}
\makeatother                                    

\makeatletter                           % Author
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\centering \large \@author}}               
\makeatother                            


\newcommand{\answerbox}[1][]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,width=2.5cm,enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,sharp corners,#1]
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newtcolorbox{notesbox}[2][]{nobeforeafter,boxrule=0pt,colback=white,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners,width=\linewidth,height=#2,#1}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_jon_topics_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillTopicsList}{m}{%
  \clist_set:Nn \g_jon_topics_clist {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayTopicsList}{O{}}{%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_jon_topics_clist { ##1: & \answerbox[#1] \tabularnewline}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\MakeTable}{O{}mmO{Notes(Calculations/Odours}D<>{0.4\textheight}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{m{#2}m{#3}}
    \tabularnewline
    \DisplayTopicsList[#1]
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{%
      #4
    }\tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{2}{|@{}l@{}|}{%
      \begin{notesbox}[#1]{#5}
      \end{notesbox}
    }\tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
\section*{Data}
\FillTopicsList{Boiling point at first drop,Boiling point at last drop,
  Tared flask weight with decanted solution (1.0 mg),
  Mass of essential oil after evaporation,
  Percent of essential oil based on mass of caraway oil
  Mass of 2,4-DNP (\ce{C16H18O4N4}), 
  Melting point of 2,4-DNP, 
  Amount of carvone originally extracted, 
  Amount of limonene in the oil, 
  Percent of limonene,
  Percent of carvone,
}

\MakeTable{6cm}{2.5cm}<0.3\textheight>

\MakeTable[colback={yellow!40!white}]{6cm}{2.5cm}<0.3\textheight>


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems perfect.. Will play around to tweak it so it still fits on the previous page with the rest of the content and make the rows fit on the same line without wrapping, but wow, this will be very useful will definitely reuse this for other labs.  Thank you so much!  This community is awesome!

Comment: @JonWeinraub: You're welcome ... of course you've to change some parameters. If you've some questions about the `ExplSyntaxOn` features, don't hesitate (I learned it too during the last days ;-))

Comment: What causes the size of the table so I can "shrink" it so I can fit it in the previous page?

Comment: @JonWeinraub: I would say the height of the `notes` box. `\MakeTable{6cm}{2.5cm}<0.2\textheight>`  The value in the `<...>` bracket pair controls the height of the notes box